# Django Rest-Framework search-fields wont work inside @action

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to use the search field offered by DRF inside of an action, but it seems to not work. I had a similar problem paginating inside of the action but found a solution. My guess is that it's overriding the ModelViewSet so I have to manually add the filtering, but is there a way to use the same search_fields offered by DRF.  Here's my code:

```
class XViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = X.objects.all()
    serializer_class = XSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter,OrderingFilter)
    search_fields = ['a','b','c','d']
    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
    def me(self, request):
        query = X.objects.filter(ex_id=request.user.id)
        if request.method == 'GET':
            
            serializer = XSerializer(query, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

Any help is appreciated, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by importing the query param in the beginning, and then filtered the queryset, here's the updated code:

```
class XViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = X.objects.all()
    serializer_class = XSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter,OrderingFilter)
    search_fields = ['a','b','c','d']
    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
    def me(self, request):
        query = self.get_queryset()
        query = query.filter(ex_id=request.user.id)
        if request.method == 'GET':
            query = self.filter_queryset(query)
            serializer = XSerializer(query, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

There's probably a better way to write this code but Just wanted to share it with everyone.